# Method hexnumber giving false

Tags: c#

This method should return, if the string contains hex, `true` else `false`. I have the following problem my Input is `2D` so it should return `true` but is returning `false` instead

```
static bool IsHexNumber(string s)
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        char zeichen = s[i];
        if("ABCDEFabcdef0123456789".Contains(zeichen))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Could anyone point out where the error on my code is?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question or describe the problem you're having.  We aren't normally psychic.

Comment: When my input is 2D it should give True , but it gives False, but this guy gave me already an answer. Thanks,

Comment: So you aren't going to improve your question because you already got an answer?  -1

Comment: I did @Amy " 
When my input is 2D it should give True , but it gives False" here is the problem :)

Comment: That isn't a question, nor have you edited your question to improve it.

Comment: U asked me in comm You forgot to ask a question or describe the problem , so i did that i described my problem in the comm...

Comment: **Edit your question**, and improve it.  People should not have to come to the comments to understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix your problem, u could use else too if u want, but this way is faster,clearly..

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        char zeichen = s[i];
        if("ABCDEFabcdef0123456789".Contains(zeichen) == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your condition can be simplified.  `!"ABCDEFabcdef0123456789".Contains(zeichen)`  In general it's considered bad practice to compare to a boolean like you're doing.

Comment: Your answer would be better if you explained what the problem was with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Linq.
It will make your code shorter and simpler to read:

```
private static readonly HashSet<char>  charSet
  = new HashSet<char>("ABCDEFabcdef0123456789");

static bool IsHexNumber(string s)
{
    return s.All(c => charSet.Contains(c));
}
```

And even shorter if you are using `C# 6`:

```
static bool IsHexNumber(string s)
    => s.All(c => charSet.Contains(c));
```

Note: I'm using `HashSet` because it `Contains` will have `O(1)` complexity. `Enumerable.Contains` extension method have linear complexity `O(N)`